# Can someone explain the term QUEUE=* rake resque:work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

On Ruby on Rails I need to start a 'rescue' task.
To let this work the command `QUEUE=* rake resque:work` must be executed in a new terminal (macOS).

But: Can someone explain what this actually means?

Comment: It sets the environment variable ``QUEUE`` to ``*`` and then runs ``rake rescue:work`` (which presumably looks at ``QUEUE`` at some point).

Comment: To concat commands, I did expect a || or && ?

Comment: It’s a bash convention for setting env variables that only have duration for the command. Saves setting and unsetting after each command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resque worker will keep on polls redis queues for pending jobs. So, we need to pass queue names as args to resque task while starting the task. `QUEUE=*` is doing the same here.

So, here your question can be breakdown to 2 parts,

1. what is the purpose of `QUEUE`
2. What is the purpose of `*`

`QUEUE`:

In ruby we can do this in 4 ways.

1. Rake args:

   `rake resque:work[*]`

   For this to work resque task should have the following convention

   ```
   task :work, [:queues] do |t, args|
    queues = args[:queues]
    #do some thing with queues
   end
   ```
2. ARGV:

   `rake resque:work *`

   For this to work resque task should be like

   ```
    task :work do
      ARGV.each { |a| task a.to_sym do ; end } # to prevent multiple tasks
      queues = ARGV[0]
      # do some thing with the queues
   end
   ```
3. Options:

   `rake resque:work --queues=*`

   Again task should look like,

   ```
    task :work do
     options = {}
     OptionParser.new do |opts|
       opts.banner = "Usage: rake add [options]"
       opts.on("-q", "--queues ARG", String) { |queues| options[:queues] = queues }
     end.parse!
     # do some thing with options[:queues]
    end
   ```
4. ENV variables:

   `QUEUE=* rake resque:work`

   For this task should be like,

   ```
    task :work do
       #use  ENV['queues']
    end
   ```

Our resque library using the 4th approach for this. So you are actually setting the env variable here with the `QUEUE=*`.

The same we can break into 2 lines using the following code.

```
export QUEUE=*
rake resque:work
```

**Now coming to * part:**

`*` is a wildcard char that tells resque to listen to all the queues in the redis. But priority will be alphabetical order. If you dont want this we can call task with specific queues also like

`QUEUES="queue1,queue2" rake resque:work`

So, here resque task will pull jobs from only queue1 and queue2, with queue1 having high priority.

**`rake resque:work`**:

`rake`: is a command to initiate task

`resque`: is namespace to group tasks under a name

`work`: is a task name